# Java extension class loader loads JAR files with any extension or no extension

Tags: java, classloader

On Windows using Java 8 ...

I recently started supporting a legacy app that deployed their Java code (single jar file) into the JDK extensions directory `$JAVA_HOME/lib/ext`.  This is the location that is used by the Java extension class loader.  It's an unusual way to load app code, but it works.  I changed the extension of the jar file from `.jar` file to `.BAK` thinking that the file would be ignored.  To my surprise the classes still loaded from the renamed file.  It seems that the extension class loader will load all files from `$JAVA_HOME/lib/ext` regardless of the file extension, or even files with no extension.  This is different from the application class loader, which only loads files with `.jar` or `.JAR` extension when placed inside a folder that is referenced by `-cp ".;./folder/*"`.

Why the inconsistency with the extension class loader?  Is this by design or a bug?  I could not find any Oracle documentation on this just blogs.

Comment: You’re riding a dead horse. The extension loader is going to disappear completely…

Comment: Yes, the extension loader is going away in newer versions of Java, but Java 8 will be around for many years.